# How to turn on/off voice typing

Tags: htc

I have a HTC One X+ and I was using voice typing very well, however I accidentally turned this off or disabled it and I am unable to turn it back on. I am new to the Android system and this was done in error.

How can I re-enable voice typing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ICS (android 4.0), do the following to change your input method.

Goto `Settings -> Language and input -> Keyboard and input methods`  Then check the box in front of the menu item `Google voice typing`

Now you can select the voice typing as your input method.