# I have an HTC desire C and want to turn off Google voice typing

Tags: voice-recognition, htc-desire-c

The keyboard is so small that I keep hitting the voice typing microphone icon but I don't want to use that feature ever. It's too slow and lags.

So, I want to turn it off completely. Under settings>language & keyboard> keyboard & input methods, there is no option to turn it off.

This thread: [How to turn on/off voice typing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37505/how-to-turn-on-off-voice-typing) is similar but addresses another model that does appear to have an on/off feature or box to check to enable or disable. HTC Desire C does not seem to.

So how can I turn it off or disable it?

Answer (score -1):

Disable both Google Voice Typing (in the keyboard menu) as well as Voice Input key (under Languages).